# Trying to thunkify a callback based function to use with generators (yield), doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, koa

I am trying to synchronously invoke a regular call-back style function in koa using generators.  The following approach works:

```
  var res = yield function (cb) {
    myDaoObject.load(function (err, res) {
       cb(err, res);
    })
  };
```

So I wont to replace it with the proper library use which should be equivalent:

```
var ld = thunkify(myDaoObject.load);
var res = yield ld();
```

And that doesn't work.  Aren't these supposed to be the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you hardly need to use `thunkify` here, as your function doesn't take an argument. You can (and should) however simplify it to

```
yield function(cb) { myDaoObject.load(cb); }
```

and possibly even further to just

```
yield myDaoObject.load;
```

which would work if `load` was not a method that used `this`. You will have to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it to the object you want it get called upon:

```
yield myDaoObject.load.bind(myDaoObject);
```

The same problem was with your `thunkify` call - which was otherwise fine (albeit unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks!  Sigh.  This is why I hate JavaScript -- it's one of the very few languages you need to actually know to be able to use.